# passing the element "I" in a loop in square brackets

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, element

Happy new year.
I'm currently studying Python and having fun with it. I'm new to coding all together.
Wanted to find out what is this process or technique called below and what is the logic of it:

```
for i in range(len(split_string)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        empty_string2 += (split_string_upper[i] + " ")
    else:
        empty_string2 += (split_string_lower[i] + " ")
```

in the code block above, I was struggling with working with the index of the 'split_string' string. I didn't know how to bypass treating the index as a numerical value and actually work with its represented character, so I'd get a typical 'can't mix str and int' error.

After watching some videos I saw a programmer do what I've called "passing in the element".
Just wanted to know what is the actual name of this method, and what is it officially doing?
(I've of course got an idea what its doing as it's produced desired outcome, but not to the extent that I could troubleshoot issues that may be related or explain to someone else.)

Here is the full code for wider context:

```
users_string2 = input("Please enter a string: ")

users_string2_caps = users_string2.upper()
users_string2_low = users_string2.lower()

split_string = users_string2.split()

split_string_upper = users_string2_caps.split()
split_string_lower = users_string2_low.split()

empty_string2 = "" #STRING

for i in range(len(split_string)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        empty_string2 += (split_string_upper[i] + " ")
    else:
empty_string2 += (split_string_lower[i] + " ")`

print(empty_string2)
```

Many thanks in advance.
Lekky

Got desired result/outcome

Answer (score 0):

`split_string_upper[i]` [*indexes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) (or *slice* if you use the slice notation `[a:b]`) the string `split_string_upper` at position `i`.  When you are doing that in a loop you could call it *iteration*.